# i need a way to show records on a new form by clicking on a datagridview on another form

Tags: mysql, datagridview, combobox, openform

I have a form with a datagridview showing inventory.  the inventory table has a field called unitid.

i want it to work such that when i select a record from the inventory datagridview it must open another from e.g frminventorydetails, and show all the fields in textboxes and combo boxes from the record i selected.

i have it working but the problem is the combobox.  it does not show the correct value in the combobox.  when the details form loads i have a method to load the combobox with values from the units table.  but when the details form loads it does not go to the appropriate displaymember.

it works perfectly when i put the combo box in the same form as the inventory datagrid.  but does not work when the combobox is n another form.

```
  private void dginventory_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            try
            {
                string getdetails = @"select * from tblinventory where
                tblinventory.invid='" + Convert.ToInt32(dginventory.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + "'";

                performqueries.singleResult(getdetails);

                frmviewinvdetails invdetopen = new frmviewinvdetails();

                if (performqueries.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    invdetopen.txtinvid.Text = performqueries.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("invid").ToString();
                    invdetopen.txtinvcode.Text = performqueries.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("InventoryCode").ToString();
                    invdetopen.txtInvDescription.Text = performqueries.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("InvDescription").ToString();
                    invdetopen.txtInvShortText.Text = performqueries.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("InvShortText").ToString();

                    //here im assigning the unitid to the selectedvalue property of the combobox in the details form.
                    invdetopen.cbunits.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(performqueries.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("unitid").ToString());

                    }

                   invdetopen.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                //throw;
            }

    // this fills the combobox on the details form when it loads
    private void frmviewinvdetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SqlConfig performcrud = new SqlConfig();
        string units = "select * from tblunits";
        performcrud.fill_CBO(units, cbunits);
    }
```

i expect the combo box to display the appropriate unit description for the particilar item i selected, but instead it just remains on the first record.

it works if the combobox is on the same form as the datagrid but not if im opening a new form.

Comment: i think invdetopen.cbunits i'ts not initialized correctly. Check on the invdetopen.cbunits.DataSource stored before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code for setting the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` of the `cbunits`. Make sure that those properties are set, then the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` is set and *finally* you can use `SelectedValue`.

Also, this might be a problem:

```
string units = "select * from tblunits";
```

You *must* match the property (Diplay and Value) names, so I'd strongly recommend to use specific field names in SQL. I don't know if it even works with '*'. *Edit: I tested it, it does work with the asterix, so you only need to make sure the field names are matching.*. Also using `DataTable` as the `DataSource` would be an advantage:

```
dt Datatable = FunctionToGetDataTable("select ID, UnitName as UnitName from tblunits");
```

So then you can use:

```
invdetopen.cbunits.ValueMember = "ID";
invdetopen.cbunits.ValueMember = "UnitName";
invdetopen.cbunits.ValueMember = dt;
```

You should always be able to stop your code with breakpoint and look into the variables. If you use `DataTable`, you can take advantage of DataTable Visualizer (click the little magnifying glass over "dt") in the debugging mode and you'll actually see it as a table.

It doesn't take more than those few lines above, if it is done correctly.